# Cant type System.IO.Ports shorthand

Tags: c#, namespaces, serial-port

I have the following code but still have to type full path to use the System.IO.Ports namespace even though I have the using clause in place. Am I missing something in my reference list?

The = new SerialPort returns a Error 5  'SerialPort' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialPort
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort counter = new SerialPort("COM5");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a namespace of `SerialPort`. Don't do that. That's what's causing the problem.

All you've got to do is change the namespace, and you'll be fine. You *could* use an alias as per Honza's request, but I think the code would be clearer to everyone if you just renamed the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your namespace carries the same name. Either rename your namespace or use an alias for the serial port, like this:

```
using SP = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
```

And then you can use

```
SP counter = new SP("COM5");
```

But as Jon suggested, renaming your namespace is a clearer solution to anyone who'll read your code.